# Getting music to play across account switching

Tags: 14.04, sound, users, music

I am using Unity in 14.04.3 LTS.  I frequently switch users.  Click the gear in the upper right corner and switch account.

I can play music in various ways but when I switch account it stops.  When I come back to the original account it resumes.  This happens even when I log in via ssh as root and play the music there (it applies to the account that was active when the music playing started).

**I would like to have a way to play music consistently as I switch user/account.   How can I do this?**

I would prefer to play music from a command line as I have a script to play my lists and to play the parameters I want, such as speed (some music I play slower).  I play it on the laptop speakers (not headphones).

*Edit:*

It looks like pulseaudio *server process per user* is the likely culprit.

Comment: usefull thread to see:
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1417647

Comment: that thread refers to System->User Settings->Advanced->User Priviledges->Use audio device but i cannot find it

Comment: that thread might be useful (lock to one user might be what i need) but i cannnot find the System menu/app (even System Settings has no User Settings submenu) in Unity on 14.04.3